# bash shell cmd in one line

Tags: bash, unix

I want to find the latest modified file and then move it to different name in one line.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
ls -t latestfile* | head -1 | xargs mv {} newfilename
```

Comment: ...in general, caring more about getting something into exactly one line than caring about correctness and corner-case handling is a dangerous place to be. That's exceptionally true in bash, where there are lots of approaches that are both simple and dangerous, but look like they work when first tested -- the worst data-loss event I've been present for was caused by someone being sloppy about their quoting, and then a program with a bug creating a filename with a whitespace-surrounded wildcard.

Comment: For what it's worth, `zsh` makes this much easier. (Correcting an earlier typo:) `mv latestfile*(om[1]) newfilename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `xargs` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
 -I replace-str

        Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names
        read from standard input. Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input
        items; instead the separator is the newline character. Implies -x and -L
```

You're using a replacement string without specifying the flag that enables it. Try:

```
ls -t latestfile* | head -1 | xargs -I {} mv {} newfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

```
mv "$(ls -t latestfile*|head -1)" newname
```

Shouldn't really be parsing the output of `ls`, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a better way in a one-liner right now...

Comment: Re: "better ways", that's exactly what [BashFAQ #99](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099) exists to document.

Comment: (To be very explicit, btw -- not my downvote; not a fan of either answer, but neither do I think either is so wrong as to be worth a -1).

Comment: Totally agree, but they aren't one-liners. I suppose you could say `files=(*) newest=${files[0]}; for f in "${files[@]}"; do [[ "$f" -nt "$newest" ]] && newest="$f"; done; mv "$newest" newname` but that's ugly, lol... As I said, shouldn't be parsing `ls`, but was answering the question asked. Either way, thanks for the BashFAQ link - was exactly what I was trying to recall so I could link it in the post, but couldn't remember it. :)

Comment: I'm not thin-skinned. XD